# How to perform this foreach loop I need?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, foreach

I have a web app that has a Diary. In this Diary, I can post updates and my friends can see it and vote. They can like, unlike, etc.

So, I take the 6 last posts, and I also have to take the votes (like, unlike, etc) for each post.

My problem is how could I get this impression votes related to the Diary post?
I tried this:

```
var impressions = "";

foreach (var item in diaryPosts)
{
    impressions = (from i in db.Impressions
                   select new ImpressionsSet
                   {
                       ImpressionID = i.ID,
                       ImpressionTitle = i.Impression,
                       ImpressionNum = i.DiaryImpressions.Count(d => d.DiaryPostsID == item.PostID)
                   }).ToList();
}
```

But with this approach, I get the error:

```
Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<...>' to 'string'
```

I would like this var 'impressions' get all impressions related to these 6 last posts I show in my page.

So, foreach Diary post I have, I would have another foreach to my impressions and its Counts but on the other hand, this var 'impressions' would have 2 foreach loops inside, one for each post, and one foreach impression.

Could anyone help me with that with a sample for my Controller and for my razor View? 
Is my explanation clear enough?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

impressions is of type string.

`var impressions = "";`

And you try to assign list to that variable.

Change it to

```
List<ImpressionSet> impressions;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Peri, now I have another question: how can I access this 2 impressions lists in my foreach loop in my view?

Comment: I just realize I need AddRange and not impressions = ... its like this: impressions.AddRange( (from i in db.Impressions...).ToList());

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var allimpressions = diaryPosts.SelectMany(dp => {
         return (from i in dp.Impressions
          select new ImpressionsSet
          {
           ImpressionID = i.ID,
           ImpressionTitle = i.Impression,
           ImpressionNum = i.DiaryImpressions.Count(d => d.DiaryPostsID == dp.PostID)
          }).ToList();
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var allimpressions = 
    from dp in diaryPosts
    from i in dp.Impressions
    let count = i.DiaryImpressions.Count (di => di.DiaryPostsID == dp.PostID)
    select new { ImpressionID = i.ID, ImpressionTitle = i.Impression, ImpressionNum = count };
```